# Insert into table value for rows fetched from previous query if not exists

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have 2 tables , let's say `'ACCESSENTRY'` and `PROJECT` ., and `PROJECT` contains columns **ROLE, ACCESSENTRY**.  I need to find first rows that **ACCESSENTRY** is equal to 'A' and for these rows insert into `ACCESSENTRY` new rows with fetched '**ROLE**' and given **ACCESSENTRY**, but if this row does not exist.
So let's say within this query:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT ... SELECT` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
insert into UM_ACCESSENTRY(role, accessentry) 
select p.role, 'test' 
from UM_PROJECT p 
where p.PROJECT='ProjectName'
and not exists (
  select 1 from UM_ACCESSENTRY a
  where a.role = p.role and a.accessentry = 'test'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
insert into ROLEE (role, accessentry) 
    select r.role, 'ACCESS'
    from ROLEE r
    where r.ACCESSENTRY = 'A' and
          not exists (select 1 from rolee r2 where r2.role = r.role and r2.column2 = 'ACCESS');
```